# How do I list my devices in GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub, kernel

I am trying to boot my own simple OS kernel using GRUB `stage2_eltorito`. However, the compiled ISO simply leads to a GRUB prompt. I looked up online, and I saw I need to load my kernel. However, when I try to load my kernel, it says I need to load a hard disk first, using the `root` command. How do I load my ISO file's partition to load my kernel? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is your howto:

https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux

or here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/38082/how-do-i-manually-boot-from-the-grub-prompt-after-do-release-upgrade

In short:

```
grub> set pager=1
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub> ls (hd0,1)/
lost+found/ bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/
lib64/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/ 
srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ vmlinuz vmlinuz.old 
initrd.img initrd.img.old
```

This is just example, you have to modify it to your situation. You have examples in linked howtos.

Comment: Thank you!! `ls (hd0, gptX)`, where X is partition number, worked for me and I finally found out where my OS was located

Answer (score 9):

The grub `ls -l` command will show all devices and partitions with their UUID-s.

[thanks to](https://askubuntu.com/a/228038/138940)

Comment: `ls -l` is not valid because `-l` is not a valid option for ls.  You will get the error `error: file '-l' not found`

Comment: @shrewmouse Please check the version of GRUB you are using, I believe this applies to version 2 only.

Comment: It's grub2 and the documentation that you link to doesn't even have the a -l option.

Comment: It works when in the GRUB command prompt, before booting the OS. I have just checked, I have GRUB version 2.04.

Comment: OK, this is fun.  I'm using grub 2.02.  Sorry.  Carry on.

Comment: `ls -l` worked for me. Ubuntu MATE 21.04.

Comment: `ls -l` also worked for me in grub of Linux Mint 20.02